# CRTP - How to call the base class implemention of a method from the derived class?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I am currently messing around with the CRTP pattern using C++ templates.  While fiddling around with visual studio i found several ways/methods in which a derived class can call the base class implementation of a function.  Below is the code i am using and also 3 commented out lines showing how call the base class implementation of a function from a derived class.  Is there a benefit to using one method over another?  Are there any differences?  What is the most comonly used method?

```
template<typename T>
struct ConsoleApplication
{

    ConsoleApplication()
    {
        auto that = reinterpret_cast<T*>(this);
        that->ShowApplicationStartupMsg();
    }



    void ShowApplicationStartupMsg()
    {

    }
};


struct PortMonitorConsoleApplication : ConsoleApplication < PortMonitorConsoleApplication >
{
    void ShowApplicationStartupMsg()
    {
        // __super::ShowApplicationStartupMsg();
        // this->ShowApplicationStartupMsg();
        // ConsoleApplication::ShowApplicationStartupMsg();
    }
};
```

Comment: Why do the base and derived classed both need `ShowApplicationStartupMsg()` ? If the derived does nothing but call the base, you should omit the version in the derived class.

Comment: Only one of those three is a valid way of calling the hidden base method.

Comment: Your base class constructor has undefined behavior. The base is in the process of being initialized but none of the members of the derived instance and none of its members have been initialized yet. You are calling into an object that has not been completely initialized yet. You also shouldn't be using `reinterpret_cast` here, use `static_cast` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred method I've seen is to use this:

`ConsoleApplication::ShowApplicationStartupMsg();`

This is nice since it is very clear what you're trying to do, and what parent class the method being called is from (especially useful if you're not the parent class itself is a derived class).

Answer (score 0):

```
ConsoleApplication < PortMonitorConsoleApplication >::ShowApplicationStartupMsg();
```

Use the full name of your base class.

Note that this->ShowApplicationStartupMsg() doesn't call your base, it calls your own function again.

__super isn't standard (and shouldn't become one, as it's ambiguous with multiple bases).

using ConsoleApplication:: is not entirely standard (although I think GCC accepts it) as you don't inherit from ConsoleApplication per se, just one specific instance of it.

Comment: "using ConsoleApplication:: is not entirely standard" -- It is, actually. The language would still make perfect sense if it were defined the way you think it is, it just happens not to be defined that way. :) Look up "injected-class-name", if you like.

Comment: Will do - because I know that we have a few bug reports at work because this didn't compile on some cornercase compiler.